# Compatible Gradle version for Android Studio

Tags: android

I encountered this error "This dependency should be marked as çompileOnly not compile" for `"com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.8.1"` when performing code inspection on Android Studio

Comment: And what stop you to just change `compile` to `compileOnly` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "compile" with "compileOnly". Like this:

```
compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.8.1'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that and it still can't compile

Comment: Still same error?

Comment: Yup. The "compileOnly" has to placed in Gradle file, right?

Comment: Yes but I am not sure why that is happening.